# How do I separate the many to many by individuals in django models?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

How do I change the status for each player's payment? I cannot add a status field there as it will change the status for all the users within many to many fields, I want to customize it to have a different status for each user.

```
from django.db import models
from users.models import Profile
# Create your models here.

class Payments(models.Model):
    match = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    amount = models.DecimalField(default = 0, max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 2)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Profile)
    datespent = models.DateField('Date Spent')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want this:

```py
from django.db import models
from users.models import Profile


class PlayerPayment(models.Model):
    PENDING = 'pending'
    PAID = 'paid'
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (PENDING, 'Pending',)
        (PAID, 'Paid')
    )
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    payment_data = models.ForeignKey("PaymentData")
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=PENDING)


class PaymentData(models.Model):
    match = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    amount = models.DecimalField(default = 0, max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 2)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, through=PlayerPayment)
    datespent = models.DateField('Date Spent')
```

I took the liberty to change `Payments` to `PaymentData` because your models should be in singular form as they represent a single entity (i.e. a single row in your table).

Comment: Thank you it works fine, I was thinking of doing something similar, however, do you think there is any way where I can select multiple players at once when creating a match and their default status would be pending and whenever someone pays, the admin will be able to change the pending to paid. This way it would be easier as I do not have to create all the players status individually as there is going to be large sum of players.

Comment: If that's the case, why not store the payment status directly in the payment data? You could also add a FK pointing to the user who made the payment.